# What happens in the background of array initialization in c?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, variable-assignment

Given that this is legal

```
uint8_t bytes[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

And this is not:

```
uint8_t bytes2[4];
bytes2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

what does `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }` represent?

Am assuming it's neither an rvalue or an lvalue. A preprocessor code candy that expands to something?

Comment: no preprocessor involved. it's _initialization_ syntax only. Not assignment.

Comment: The same holds for structs...

Comment: A simple syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{1,2,3,4}` is an *initializer-list*, a particular syntax token that can only be used on the line where the array is declared.

This is regulated purely by the C standard syntax. There's no particular rationale behind it, this is just how the language is defined. In the C syntax, arrays cannot be assigned to, nor copied by assignment.

You can however dodge the syntax restrictions in several ways, to overwrite all values at once. The simplest way is just to create a temporary array and memcpy:

```
uint8_t tmp[] = {5,6,7,8};
memcpy(bytes, tmp, sizeof bytes);
```

Alternatively, use a compound literal:

```
memcpy(bytes, (uint8_t[]){5,6,7,8}, sizeof bytes);
```

If it makes sense for the specific application, you can also wrap the array in a struct to bypass the syntax restrictions:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t data [4];
} array_t;

...

array_t bytes = { .data = {1,2,3,4} };
array_t tmp   = { .data = {5,6,7,8} };
bytes = tmp; // works just fine, structs can be copied this way
```

Comment: UV'd. You might want to add that `array_t bytes = { .data = {1,2,3,4} };`, `array_t bytes = {{1,2,3,4}};` and `array_t bytes = {1,2,3,4};` are all equivalent.

Comment: @chqrlie Sure... but the first is most explicit and self-documenting. The second is old-style C90 and the 3rd is questionable style (although it will work). Many compilers give a warning for the 3rd version.

Comment: your remarks are perfectly correct, and I would not use the third for the very reason you mention, but the second has the advantage of portability to environments that do not support the C99 syntax, including many C++ compilers.

Comment: Are you sure that "token" is the right word here?  Normally a token is an indivisible atom of lexing, whereas an initiliazer-list is built of tokens like an expression.

Comment: @TobySpeight No I'm not sure but I don't think it matters unless the OP is making a compiler. Formally, an _initializer-list_ is part of an _initializer_ which is part of an _init-declarator_ which is part of an _init-declarator-list_, which is part of a _declaration_. So what, this is not something that the average programmer needs to know.

Comment: Kindly do not copy parts of other answers into mine, particularly with no attribution given - makes it look as if the text is stolen. It is perfectly fine to have several answers posted that complement each other. Just up-vote all useful answers and mark the most useful one as accepted.

Comment: To be exact, `{1,2,3,4}` is not initializer list. `1,2,3,4` is initializerlist in this case. The whole thing - `{1,2,3,4}` - is a *brace enclosed initializer list*.

Answer (score 8):

A syntax like `{1,2,3,4};` is called brace-enclosed initializer list, it's an *initializer*. It can be only used for initialization (for array type).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

- P11

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression,

*[an array is not a scalar type, so not applicable for us]*

- P14

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string
>   literal, optionally enclosed in braces.

*[We are not using a string literal here, so also not applicable for us]*

- P16

> Otherwise, the initializer for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be a brace-enclosed
>   list of initializers for the elements or named members.

*[This is the case of our interest]*

and, P17,

> Each **brace-enclosed initializer list** has an associated current object. When no
>   designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according
>   to the type of the current object: **array elements in increasing subscript order**, structure
>   members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union.[....]

So, here, the values from the brace enclosed list are not directly "assigned" to the array, they are used to initialize individual members of the array.

OTOH, an array type, is **not** a modifiable lvalue, so it cannot be assigned. In other words, an array variable cannot be used as the LHS of the assignment operator.

To elaborate, from `C11`, chapter §6.5.16

> assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

Comment: So far i have been perceiving `initialization` as `declaration + assignment` which seems not to fit for the above example. What would be your definition of initialization?

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer Beware, they have different contraints.

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer I've updated with relevant references, see if that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant to say this... But just in case: in C anything can be uinitialized by a brace enclosed initilaizer list. `int x = { 42 };` is perfectly legal in C. In this case `42` is the *initializer*. And it is a single expression, just as required.

Answer (score 5):

Initialization and assignment are fundamentally different things. As for the language C, you just have to accept the fact that they are distinguished, but of course, there's a technical reason it's defined this way:

In many systems, you can have a *data segment* in your executable file. This segment could be read/write and given an initialized array like

```
uint8_t foo[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // assume this has static storage duration
```

the compiler could just decide to output this exact byte sequence directly into your executable. So there's **no code at all** doing an assignment, the data is already there in memory when your program starts.

---

OTOH, arrays cannot be assigned to (only their individual members). That's how C is defined, and it's sometimes unfortunate.

Answer (score 3):

`{1,2,3,4}` is an initializer list. It an be used to specify the initial value of an object with at least 4 elements, be they array elements or structure members including those of nested objects.

You cannot use this syntax to assign values to an array as this:

```
bytes2 = {1,2,3,4};
```

Because the syntax is not supported, and arrays are not lvalues.

You can use intializer lists as part of a C99 syntax known as compound literals to create objects and use them as rvalues for assignment, return values or function arguments:

```
struct quad { int x, y, z, t; };

struct quad p;
p = (struct quad){1,2,3,4};
```

You still cannot use this for arrays because they are not lvalues, but you can achieve the same effect with a call to `memcpy()`:

```
uint8_t bytes2[4];
memcpy(bytes2, (uint8_t[4]){1,2,3,4}, sizeof(bytes2));
```

This statement is compiled by `clang` as a single intel instruction as can be seen on [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/nFutFU)